# bibliography citation undefined

Tags: bibliographies, citing, apacite

I try everything, I spent 3 days on it.
I'm using `apacite` style in a long file - my thesis.
In the chapter references/ bibliography, it is fine.
It is not in the text (undefined)
I don't find the error and I try everything so I don't get why it is not working.

I'm using Texmaker.

main tex:

```
  \documentclass[a4paper, 12 pt]{report}
    \usepackage{apacite}
    \usepackage{geometry}
    \geometry{a4paper, top=2.6 cm, bottom=2.6 cm, left=2.6 cm, right=2.6 cm}
    \begin{document}    
    text tex \cite{Gregory_2002, Stone_Baron-Cohen_Knight_1998} tex tex tex \cite{Smith_2015}
    \chapter{Conclusions}
        \bibliographystyle{apacite}
        \bibliography{References}
    \end{document}
```

some entries in the bib file:

```
@article{Gregory_2002,
title={Theory of mind in patients with frontal variant frontotemporal dementia and Alzheimer’s disease: theoretical and practical implications},
 author={Gregory AND Carol AND Lough AND Sinclair AND Stone AND Valerie AND Erzinclioglu AND Sharon AND Martin AND Louise AND Baron‐Cohen AND Simon AND Hodges AND John}, 
  journal={Brain},  
    year={2002},
  pages={752–764},
  volume={125}}
   
 @article{Hernandez-Keysers_2020,
title={Harm to Others Acts as a Negative Reinforcer in Rats}, 
 author={Hernandez-Lallement, Julen and Attah, Augustine Triumph and Soyman, Efe and Pinhal, Cindy M. and Gazzola, Valeria and Keysers, Christian},
   journal={Current Biology},  
      year={2020},
     pages={949-961.e7},
     volume={30}}

  @book{Smith_2015, 
author*={Smith}, 
 title={Qualitative Psychology: A Practical Guide to Research Methods},
  publisher={SAGE Publications}, 
    year={2015},
  ISBN={978-1-4739-3341-5}, 
  url={https://books.google.co.uk/books?id=lv0aCAAAQBAJ}}

 @article{Stone_Baron-Cohen_Knight_1998, 
author={Stone AND Valerie AND Baron-Cohen AND Simon AND Knight AND Robert T.},  
title={Frontal Lobe Contributions to Theory of Mind}, 
 journal={Journal of Cognitive Neuroscience},  
   year={1998},
  pages={640–656},
   volume={10}}

 @article{Turken_Dronkers_2011, 
author={Turken, And U. and Dronkers, Nina F.},  
 title={The Neural Architecture of the Language Comprehension Network: Converging Evidence from Lesion and Connectivity Analyses},
  journal={Frontiers in System Neuroscience},
    year={2011},
  volume={5} }
```

I don't have any idea why is not working, could be i have too many file in the work?
I don't know I really finish any idea. please help me!
They give me undefined citation. it does not appear just in the body text

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE.

Comment: The `.bib` file also has a very interesting style of indentation, you may want to go for a more clean style.

Comment: Off-topic: The instruction `\geometry{a4paper, top=2.6 cm, bottom=2.6 cm, left=2.6 cm, right=2.6 cm}` may be rephrased more succinctly as `\geometry{a4paper, margin=2.6cm}`.

Comment: Thank you to everyone!
I will improve my bibliography!
I also was able to produce the citation in the text I was so disparate that I start to delete a package each time and try to run and in the end there was interference.
So if someone has the same problems it could be the final solution.

Comment: Thanks you so much everybody

Answer (score 3):

There is a `*` in

```
author*={Smith}
```

in `Smith_2015` that shouldn't be there. The `*` causes BibTeX to ignore the `author` field of that entry. You need to remove `*`. You'll also want to make sure to give the full name (Jonathan A. Smith) and use the correct field `editor` here instead of `author`.

```
editor = {Jonathan A. Smith},
```

---

The `.bib` file also contains the very interesting name

```
author = {Turken, And U. and Dronkers, Nina F.},
```

which is problematic, because `and` is the keyword that separates multiple authors. One easy way to stop BibTeX getting confused here is to use a `~` to tie the `And` to the `U.`.

```
author = {Turken, And~U. and Dronkers, Nina F.},
```

Alternatively, you can use curly braces

```
author = {Turken, {And} U. and Dronkers, Nina F.},
```

as suggested by [Mico](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/5001/mico) in [the comments](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/550308/bibliography-citation-undefined/550310?noredirect=1#comment1389951_550310).

---

Some of your entries had wrongly formatted `author` fields with `and`s in wrong places, you might want to check those out as well, see the cleaned up entries below.

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 12 pt]{report}
\usepackage{apacite}

\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@article{Gregory_2002,
  title   = {Theory of Mind in Patients With Frontal Variant
             Frontotemporal Dementia and {Alzheimer's} Disease:
             Theoretical and Practical Implications},
  author  = {Carol Gregory and Sinclair Lough and Valerie Stone
             and Sharon Erzinclioglu and Louise Martin
             and Simon Baron-Cohen and John R. Hodges},
  journal = {Brain},
  year    = {2002},
  pages   = {752–764},
  volume  = {125},
}
@article{Hernandez-Keysers_2020,
  title   = {Harm to Others Acts as a Negative Reinforcer in Rats},
  author  = {Hernandez-Lallement, Julen and Attah, Augustine Triumph
             and Soyman, Efe and Pinhal, Cindy M. and Gazzola, Valeria
             and Keysers, Christian},
  journal = {Current Biology},
  year    = {2020},
  pages   = {949-961.e7},
  volume  = {30},
}
@book{Smith_2015,
  editor    = {Jonathan A. Smith},
  title     = {Qualitative Psychology:
               A Practical Guide to Research Methods},
  publisher = {SAGE Publications},
  year      = {2015},
  ISBN      = {978-1-4739-3341-5},
  url       = {https://books.google.co.uk/books?id=lv0aCAAAQBAJ},
}
@article{Stone_Baron-Cohen_Knight_1998,
  author  = {Valerie E. Stone and Simon Baron-Cohen and Robert T. Knight},
  title   = {Frontal Lobe Contributions to Theory of Mind},
  journal = {Journal of Cognitive Neuroscience},
  year    = {1998},
  pages   = {640–656},
  volume  = {10},
}
@article{Turken_Dronkers_2011,
  author  = {Turken, And~U. and Dronkers, Nina F.},
  title   = {The Neural Architecture of the
             Language Comprehension Network:
             Converging Evidence from Lesion and Connectivity Analyses},
  journal = {Frontiers in System Neuroscience},
  year    = {2011},
  volume  = {5},
}
\end{filecontents}

\begin{document}    
text tex \cite{Gregory_2002, Stone_Baron-Cohen_Knight_1998} tex tex tex \cite{Smith_2015}
\cite{Turken_Dronkers_2011,Hernandez-Keysers_2020}
\chapter{Conclusions}
\bibliographystyle{apacite}
\bibliography{\jobname}
\end{document}
```

[image: text tex (Gregory et al., 2002; Stone, Baron-Cohen, & Knight, 1998) tex tex tex (Smith, 2015) (Turken & Dronkers, 2011; Hernandez-Lallement et al., 2020)]

[image: Gregory, C., Lough, S., Stone, V., Erzinclioglu, S., Martin, L., Baron-Cohen, S., & Hodges, J. R. (2002). Theory of mind in patients with frontal variant frontotemporal dementia and alzheimer’s disease: Theoretical and practical implications. Brain, 125, 752–764.]

Comment: @Mico Even better: show he's the editor of the work: `editor = {Jonathan A. Smith},`

Comment: Another method for informing BibTeX that a certain instance of "And" is a given name rather than a keyword is to encase it in curly braces: `author={Turken, {And} U. and ...}`.

Comment: @Mico Thanks. Good point. That is actually what `biblatex` suggests you do. (But then I'm personally not too fond of all the curly braces in `.bib` files.)